# Google maps en xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación la cual utiliza la API de Google Maps.
en esta aplicación muestro el mapa y en el mapa me aparecen marcados los lugares de interés de la zona en la que se encuentra la cámara. 
Ejemplo: Almacenes, supermercados, iglesias, etc, etc.
Como se puede eliminar o dejar de mostrarlos?

Comment: ni siquiera encuentro la forma de sacar los pines desde google maps. y la opcion no esta disponible como una propiedad. Quizas hay alguna forma haciendo un custom control con el mapa.